# How to get the command line used by Visual Studio 2010 for MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Is there a way to see the default command line arguments that Visual Studio 2010 uses for deploying a project?

Comment: Deploying what kind of project?

Comment: I'm deploying an ASP.NET MVC application.